# List out stored procedures with in the stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

SQL stored procedures used some inner stored procedures.so I want to get all inner used stored procedures list in specific stored procedure in SQL server.i am using SQL server 2008.please help to find this solution.

Comment: You can check the dependencies of stored procedure in SQL Management studio. Right Click on the particular stored proc and click View Dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to find the dependency

EXEC sp_depends @objName = N'Stored_Procedure_Name'

Comment: its working fine.but it displayed containing table and view also.if any possible to display stored procedures only

Comment: @CSK - be aware that sp_depends can give incorrect information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information_schema.routines combined with sys.sql_expression_dependencies - but you need it in a recursive fashion.

```
with recursedProcs(code_database, ancestorName, object, Recursion, procpath)    
as 
(
    select isr.specific_catalog as code_database, isr.[specific_name] as ancestorName, cast(isr.specific_name as varchar(200)) as object, 1 as Recursion, cast(isr.specific_name as varchar(200)) as procpath
    from information_schema.routines isr with (nolock)
    union all 
    select p.code_database, p.ancestorName,  cast(d.referenced_entity_name as varchar(200)), p.recursion + 1, cast(p.procpath + '/' + cast(d.referenced_entity_name as varchar(200)) as varchar(200)) 
    from recursedProcs p
    inner join sys.sql_expression_dependencies d on d.referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(p.object)
    where p.recursion < 20
    and d.referenced_id <> object_id(p.object)
)
select * from recursedProcs
```

This recurses down every procedure in the database, through sub-procedures and finally to the tables that a procedure depends on. From this starting point you can refine it to suit your needs. (If you have more than 20 levels deep of sub-procedures, you will also need to add a maxrecursion option and remove the <20 predicate)

sp_depends is deprecated going forward and does currently have the ability to give incorrect answers.